# Install OS X/macOS on a Mac mini without a keyboard (10.11 El Capitan/10.12 Sierra)

Tags: macos, network, mac-mini, server.app, remote-desktop

How do you configure OS X/macOS on a (headless) Mac mini without a keyboard?

- The Mac mini is connected via ethernet
- A MacBook Pro is connected to the same network via ethernet
- The Mac mini is at the first screen of a new OS X 10.11 installation

I want to login to the Mac mini using ARD (Apple Remote Desktop) but can't use the methods of 10.6 (serial number + IP address).

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Why can't you access the Mac mini directly? It would be much easier to plug in a monitor and keyboard for setup, and then allow it to be controlled from a different computer (ARD)

Comment: I can access the Mac mini, but I won't be able to connect it to a monitor. I'll be able to connect it to a MBP using Thunderbolt, if that's of any help.

Comment: You generally can't ARD whilst the machine is in the startup phase [which I guess is really what an update is]. if you were already remoted to it before it rebooted & you keep the window open, it will auto-reconnect as soon as it can. I think this leaves you no option but to connect it physically, if you need to interact with it during setup. I can find no guide on remote OS installs, only remote software installs.